# remove repeated values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to remove the repeated value in a dictionary after I extracted the needed data which is 'rate' and 'genre'

```
a=[{'movie': 'abc', 'rate': '9', 'origin': 'AU', 'genre': 'horror'},
   {'movie': 'xyz', 'rate': '7', 'origin': 'NY', 'genre': 'romance'},
   {'movie': 'jkl', 'rate': '9', 'origin': 'HK', 'genre': 'horror'},
   {'movie': 'qwe', 'rate': '6', 'origin': 'HK', 'genre': 'comedy'},
   {'movie': 'vbn', 'rate': '9', 'origin': 'BKK', 'genre': 'romance'}]

needed_data=[]
for test in a:
    x={}
    word=['rate','genre']
    for key,value in test.items():
        for words in word:
            if key == words:
                x[key] = value

    needed_data.append(x)

results = {}
filters=[]
for yy in needed_data:
    for key,value in yy.items():
        if value not in results.values():
            results[key] = value
    filters.append(results)
print(filters)
```

the output from above code is

```
[{'rate': '9', 'genre': 'romance'}, 
{'rate': '9', 'genre': 'romance'}, 
{'rate': '9', 'genre': 'romance'}, 
{'rate': '9', 'genre': 'romance'}, 
{'rate': '9', 'genre': 'romance'}]
```

my desired output would be

```
[{'rate': '9', 'genre': 'horror'}, 
{'rate': '7', 'genre': 'romance'},  
{'rate': '6', 'genre': 'comedy'}, 
{'rate': '9', 'genre': 'romance'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use pandas for data processing

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df_dd= df[["genre", "rate"]].drop_duplicates()
new_a = df_dd.to_dict(orient="records")
print(new_a)
```

Output

```
[{'genre': 'horror', 'rate': '9.'}, 
 {'genre': 'romance', 'rate': '7'}, 
 {'genre': 'horror', 'rate': '9'}, 
 {'genre': 'comedy', 'rate': '6'}, 
 {'genre': 'romance', 'rate': '9'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data has strings '9.' and '9' Do you want it that way?

```
z = {f"{float(x['rate']):.2f}-{x['genre']}": x for x in needed_data}  
list(z.values())
```

Output

```
[{'rate': '9', 'genre': 'horror'},
 {'rate': '7', 'genre': 'romance'},
 {'rate': '6', 'genre': 'comedy'},
 {'rate': '9', 'genre': 'romance'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easy way to do your task:

```
a=[{'movie': 'abc', 'rate': '9.', 'origin': 'AU', 'genre': 'horror'},
   {'movie': 'xyz', 'rate': '7', 'origin': 'NY', 'genre': 'romance'},
   {'movie': 'jkl', 'rate': '9', 'origin': 'HK', 'genre': 'horror'},
   {'movie': 'qwe', 'rate': '6', 'origin': 'HK', 'genre': 'comedy'},
   {'movie': 'vbn', 'rate': '9', 'origin': 'BKK', 'genre': 'romance'}]
c = []
for b in a:
    c.append({'rate':b['rate'],'genre':b['genre'] })
print(c)
```

So the Output will be:

```
[{'rate': '9.', 'genre': 'horror'}, {'rate': '7', 'genre': 'romance'}, {'rate': '9', 'genre': 'horror'}, {'rate': '6', 'genre': 'comedy'}, {'rate': '9', 'genre': 'romance'}]
```